# How to display a ComboBox in a DataGrid if the DataTable it is bound to has a list of items?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox, datatable

I have a DataSet. I don't know the contents of the set. I just have to display a table of the set in a DataGrid. I'm able to do this using the following code. Just to able to work with it, I have created my own DataSet. CustomerDataProvider is the class I have created that has a method that returns a dummy DataSet.

```
CustomerDataProvider provider = new CustomerDataProvider();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataView view = new DataView();



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ds = dataset.GetDataSet();
        table = ds.Tables[0];
        view = table.AsDataView();
        this.DataContext = view;
    }


<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dynamicGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" ColumnWidth="*"  />
</Grid>
```

Now, if the DataTable contains a bool value, the DataGrid automatically displays a CheckBox. I want to be able to automatically display a ComboBox if the DataTable contains a List of items. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: What you'er looking for is called `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of auto-generating columns, set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false, you can define the columns and bind with different fields of the `DataTable`. You can take `DataGridTemplateColumn` and provide the `CellTemplate` for the same. See the reference code below:

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot define the columns since I don't know what the DataTable would contain. The content could change every time I open the application.